# Checks if the User clicked the Facebook Like Button (Multiple Button)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I've looked for some solutions to this site and couple of other sites, still I saw some solutions yet I can't be able to apply it into my problem.

So would be glad if you help me guys.

I have this piece of code that generates facebook like button

Take note that **$fb_link[$i]** is the URL of the facebook fan page.

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < $ln_arr_linkdesc; $i++) { //Output Tickets
  echo '
    <div class="tick_cont">
      <div class="flike_cont">
        <fb:like href="'. $fb_link[$i] .'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="250" show_faces="true" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
      </div>
      <div class="ftitle_cont">'. $fb_desc[$i] .'</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  ';
  }
```

And this what it is looked like.

[image]

What my problem is, I can't validate if the user has liked the button(s), don't have any clue for it.

My Desire output should be

[image]

When the user clicked the usergamestv and Php Academy it **appends to the container** below that the user clicked/liked the corresponding page.

I already put **onclick="validate_like();"** on  button though, it doesn't work. Any solution for this stuff?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ please check out this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check source code of this link.http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/

[and here is demo](http://www.saschakimmel.com/fblike.html)